# Is it possible to set a max zoom / scale for an Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, settings, zooming, scale

For a project I want the user to be able to zoom in and out on a WebView but I don't want the user to be able to zoom the image out so far that it will show whitespace **on the bottom** (the WebView is `match_parent` for  `width` and `height`).

In other words: I would like to put a max zoom / scale on the webview with a maximum zoom  related to the image height, not width (what I have now).

How can i achieve such a functionality ?

Comment: As far as I know, possibly only through reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Normally , to make your app work consistently in all devices you have to set it as such :

`this.appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
this.appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
this.appView.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
this.appView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
this.appView.setInitialScale(0);`

Now , you have to add a viewPort meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=640,height=device-height,target-densityDpi=device-dpi,minimum-scale=1" />`

You can make changes to the  `minimum-scale` attribute to your liking to find what matches you like best.

Sometimes, however you may face a problem , when you reorient the device and it reloads in portrait or landscape.

For that  I normally use the following code which loads the desktop version of the Google homepage fully zoomed out to fit within the `webview`.

BrowserLayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Browser.java: :

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class Browser extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.BrowserLayout);

    String loadUrl = "http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&output=html";

    // initialize the browser object
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    try {
        // load the url
        browser.loadUrl(loadUrl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

so here `setUseWideViewPort(true)` loads your view port settings and scales it to the desired role or you can use `setLoadWithOverviewMode()` but it works only with API 7+.

Comment: I came as far as this but it's a very wide image (map) and it goes for the whitespace below the image.

Comment: what if you change `minimum-scale=1` to 5 or 6 ? what happens then ?

Comment: There are no changes if I do that.

Comment: Ok let me try it out. I will come back to you in afew mins

Comment: Did you add `user-scalable=yes` in your view port tag ?

Comment: Sorry, @BartBurg , I am out of ideas too. If you happen to solve this, kindly drop a note here, stating how you did that.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<meta name='viewport' content='target-densitydpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes'/>`  this to your html content you are going to display in webview.

Here you can change minimum-scale=1 as per your wish

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [webSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html) class. Example:

```
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebSettings.ZoomDensity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.ZoomDensity.html) function for this one.
Using that you can set the setDefaultZoom.